# Replace Text using Apache POI in Header/Footer not working when a dot is inside the placeholder

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I use templ4docx/Apache POI (2.0.3/3.17).
There you can set a VariablePatten like this:

```
private static final String START_PATTERN = "#{";
private static final String END_PATTERN = "}";
...
targetDocx.setVariablePattern(new VariablePattern(START_PATTERN, END_PATTERN));
```

When i use a placeholder with dots, it´s not working inside Header/Footer. In the Body with dots it works. And Images works too with placeholder and dots inside!

```
Example in Word-Template:
#{Person.Name} // works in Body NOT in Header/Footer!
#{Person.Name} // works in Body and Header/Footer!
#{Person} // works in Body and Header/Footer!
#{Image.Name} // works in Body and Header/Footer! Here i use ImageVariable instead of Textvariable.
```

I debug the code an saw the "run.setText()" is called with the right Text but in the final document it´s not.

```
@Override
public void insert(Insert insert, Variable variable) {
    if (!(insert instanceof TextInsert)) {
        return;
    }
    if (!(variable instanceof TextVariable)) {
        return;
    }

    TextInsert textInsert = (TextInsert) insert;
    TextVariable textVariable = (TextVariable) variable;
    for (XWPFRun run : textInsert.getParagraph().getRuns()) {
        String text = run.getText(0);
        if (StringUtils.contains(text, textInsert.getKey().getKey())) {
            text = StringUtils.replace(text, textVariable.getKey(), textVariable.getValue());
            if (text.contains("\n")) {
                String[] textLines = text.split("\n");
                run.setText(textLines[0], 0);
                for (int i = 1; i < textLines.length; i++) {
                    run.addBreak();
                    run.setText(textLines[i]);
                }
            } else {
                run.setText(text, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas why it didn´t work with Placeholder "#{Person.Name}" as a TextVariable in Header/Footer? But it works with "#{PersonName}" and ImageVariable "#{Images.Logo1}"???

Comment: You need to provide the code you're using that's "not working". There's too little information provided here to even begin guessing what the problem might be. Use the [Edit] link below the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Word sometimes separates the placeholders, so you'll only find parts of the placeholder in the runs.

In the class "TextInsertStrategy" i check in the loop of the runs for split placeholders and treat it accordingly. With that I could solve the problem.